# What is causing this invalid opcode error when I call the transfer function?

Tags: balances, transfer, address.transfer, invalid-opcode, send

I am working through the process of developing a simple ERC-20 token to learn more about smart contract development.  I am running into an issue on my coin sale contract, however.  When I wish to end the sale, I need to call the endSale() function to end the sale and to transfer all the funds (in both ether and ERC-20 tokens) back to the sale admin.  Here is that function:

```
function endSale() public payable
{
    //require admin is sender
    require(msg.sender == admin);
    //transfer remaining dapp tokens back to admin
    require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))));
    //transfer ether
    admin.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

However, when I attempt to test that function, the line `admin.transfer(address(this).balance);`, I get the error:  `Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode`.  After some testing, I have found that the portion of the code which says `address(this).balance` is the part that gives the error; when I put a regular unsigned value instead, the function calls correctly.

My full contract code and my test code is attached below.  Any help is appreciated!

Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

import "./DappToken.sol";

contract DappTokenSale
{

    address payable admin;
    DappToken public tokenContract; //holds an address of the DappToken contract
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSold;

    event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

    constructor(DappToken _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice)
    {
        //assign an admin
        admin = payable(msg.sender);
        //token contract
        tokenContract = _tokenContract; //save the address of the DappToken contract
        //token price
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
    }

    //internal: can only be called by this contract, similar to "private", pure: does not create a transaction, does not write data to blockchain
    function safeMultiply(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z)
    {
        require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x, "multiplication overflow");
    }

    //payable means ether should be able to be sent with this function
    function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable  
    {
        //require that value is equal to tokens
        require(msg.value == safeMultiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));
        //require that the contract has enough tokens
        require(tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _numberOfTokens);
        //require that a transfer is successful
        require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));
        //keep track of tokens sold
        tokensSold += _numberOfTokens;
        //trigger sell event
        emit Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
    }

    function endSale() public payable
    {
        //require admin is sender
        require(msg.sender == admin);
        //transfer remaining dapp tokens back to admin
        require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))));
        //transfer ether
        admin.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
const { writeContracts } = require("truffle");

const DappToken = artifacts.require("DappToken");
const DappTokenSale = artifacts.require("DappTokenSale");

contract('DappTokenSale', function(accounts){
    var tokenInstance;
    var tokenSaleInstance;
    var tokenPrice = 10000000000000;    //in wei
    var buyer = accounts[1];
    var admin = accounts[0];
    var tokensAvailable = 750000;
    //^give token sale contract 75% of the total 1 million tokens
    var numberOfTokens;

    
    it('ends token sale', function(){
        return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance){
            //get tokenInstance first
            tokenInstance = instance;
            return DappTokenSale.deployed();
        }).then(function(instance){
            tokenSaleInstance = instance;
            //try to end sale from non-admin account
            return tokenSaleInstance.endSale({ from: buyer });
        }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error){
            assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'must be admin to end sale');
            return tokenInstance.balanceOf(tokenSaleInstance.address);
            
        }).then(function(balance){
            assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 749990, 'balance of contract is correct still');
            //end sale as admin
            return tokenSaleInstance.endSale({ from: admin });
        }).then(function(receipt){
            return tokenInstance.balanceOf(admin);
        }).then(function(balance){
            assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 999990, 'returns all unsold dapp tokens to admin');
            return tokenInstance.balanceOf(tokenSaleInstance.address);  //if sale ended successfully, token sale contract should have no dapp tokens left
        }).then(function(price){
            assert.equal(price.toNumber(), 0, 'sale contract returned tokens to admin');
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are transferring ether (aka native token), you may want to try using a safeTransferETH function from a standard “TransferHelper” contract.

Below is a snippet from a TransferHelper contract you may want to incorporate // use for reference:

```
function safeTransferETH(address to, uint256 value) internal {
        (bool success, ) = to.call{value: value}(new bytes(0));
        require(success, 'TransferHelper::safeTransferETH: ETH transfer failed');
    }
```

Example from Uniswap V2: https://github.com/Uniswap/solidity-lib/blob/master/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol

In this case, you could theoretically use any ‘toAddress’ you specify as recipient, thus the input values would be as follows: (toAddress, address(this).balance).

Comment: Hello.  Thank you for the recommendation.  If you don't mind my asking, why is using a function like this preferable to using the transfer function.  Also, this did not solve my issue, since I still get the same error message even when I implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the issue by changing the hardfork in ganache gui from Petersburg to Muir Glacier, and then restarting the chain. I don't think this solves the core issue, but it allows my app to work by enabling the transfer of ether from the sale contract to the admin. I got the advice to switch hardforks from here:

[link](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-py/discussions/422)